# KeyError: 'Date' Am I wrong to use set_index?

Tags: python, pandas

When I run the codes,

```
import pandas as pd
import io

​
df = pd.read_table("./stock.txt", names=["ID", "Date","Open","High","Low","Close"])
df

del df['ID']

df=df.set_index(["Date"])
df
```

this error happens

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3062             try:
-> 3063                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3064             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Date'
```

I read pandas document of  set_index,
but why does such an error happen?
In first df,DataFrame showed like

```
"Date"  "Open"  "High"  "Low"  "Close"
2010-04-01 3,615  3,615   3,580   3,585
2010-04-02 3,570  3,620   3,570   3,590
　　　　 ・
　　　　 ・
　　　　 ・
```

My ideal DataFrame of second one is

```
    　　　　"Open"  "High"  "Low"  "Close"
"Date"  
2010-04-01 3,615  3,615   3,580   3,585
2010-04-02 3,570  3,620   3,570   3,590
　　　　 ・
　　　　 ・
　　　　 ・
```

To make a such an ideal  DataFrame ,how should I fix my codes?What is wrong?
My text file is like

```
1,1001 2010-04-01 3,615  3,615   3,580   3,585
2,1002 2010-04-02 3,570  3,620   3,570   3,590
　　　　 ・
　　　　 ・
　　　　 ・
```

Comment: can you show the short sample of your .txt file?

Comment: Can you check separator if `tab` ? What return `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: @jezrael When I print (df.columns.tolist()),['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'] is shown.

Comment: @user10102827 - It should working, with your sample data in my test is no problem. But I have one idea - is possible share your first 5 rows of file by gdocs, dropbox or similar? Because if copy file to question is imposible check tabs, whitespaces ans similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best is use here:

```
df = pd.read_table("./stock.txt", 
                    sep='\s+', #if separator is whitespace
                    names=["ID", "Date","Open","High","Low","Close"], 
                    parse_dates=['Date'], 
                    index_col=['Date'],
                    thousands=',')
```

Alternative:

```
df = pd.read_csv("./stock.txt", 
                 sep='\s+', #if separator is whitespace
                 names=["ID", "Date","Open","High","Low","Close"], 
                 parse_dates=['Date'], 
                 index_col=['Date'],
                 thousands=',')
```

Difference:

Default separator of `read_table` is `tab` (`sep=\t`) and for `read_csv` is comma (`sep=','`).

EDIT:

Test with your sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""1,1001 2010-04-01 3,615  3,615   3,580   3,585
2,1002 2010-04-02 3,570  3,620   3,570   3,590"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), 
                 sep="\s+", #or sep='\t' 
                 usecols=["Date","Open","High","Low","Close"],
                 names=["ID", "Date","Open","High","Low","Close"],
                 parse_dates=['Date'], 
                 index_col=['Date'],
                 thousands=',')

print (df)

            Open  High   Low  Close
Date                               
2010-04-01  3615  3615  3580   3585
2010-04-02  3570  3620  3570   3590
```